# How can i reset the cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

I am unable to do this assignment. I am new in this field. Please help.

Comment: If this assignment is part of a training course for PL/SQL, I can't help wondering how it's structured and what kind of course materials you are given prior to each test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  l_publisherid publisher.publisherid%type;
begin
  -- 1: how is PUBLISHER_ID supposed to get its value?
  --    Note that "MAX + 1" is a **bad idea** in a multiuser
  --    environment, so I just hoped that today's date fits
  l_publisherid := 10102020;
  insert into publisher (publisher_id, publisher_name)
    values (l_publisherid, 'TTK Publisher');
    
  -- 2: 
  update book b set
    b.publisherid = l_publisherid
  where b.publisherid is null;
  
  -- 3:
  dbms_output.put_line('BOOKID...TITLE.....PUBLISHER....AUTHOR');
  for cur_r in (select b.bookid, 
                       substr(b.title, 1, 10) title,
                       p.publishername,
                       a.firstname ||' '|| a.lastname author
                from book b join publisher p on p.publisherid = b.publisherid
                            join author a on a.authorid = b.author_id
                where p.publisherid = l_publisherid
               )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line
      (cur_r.book_id       ||'.....'||
       cur_r.title         ||'.....'||
       cur_r.publishername ||'.....'||
       cur_r.author
      );
  end loop;
end;
/
```